# Bootstrap carousel: how to lower the bottom circle indicators?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to lower the circle buttons in the bottom of Bootstrap 3 carousel. Here is the example at Bootstrap website: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

In this example, there are three little circles in the bottom area of the carousel. I need to move them to the bottom border. Here is what I did to lower them a bit.

```
.carousel-indicators {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

I am unable to move it further down close to the bottom edge. How can I do this?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: use a negative pixel value.

Comment: Aibrean, that works. Could you please post it as the answer? I will chose it. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a negative pixel amount on the `.carousel-indicators` bottom property you will be able to position it lower. For the Bootstrap example, for instance, you could do:

```
.carousel-indicators {
    bottom:-50px;
}
```